# Debian kernel upgrades break nvidia drivers in Debian Testing

Tags: debian, nvidia

I have tried a couple of times to install and use Debian Testing using the minimal install as a starting point. I then install nvidia drivers as instructed [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers).

Everything will work just fine for a while even through updates, until it seems, that I perform a kernel upgrade. Three times now, it appears that when I perform a kernel upgrade I now have a problem with the nvidia drivers and when booting, it seems that I reach the login screen but only the mouse appears while the rest of the screen is black.

Is there something I'm missing about using the Testing branch or upgrading?

Comment: What is your kernel version and what is your nvidia driver version? You need to keep your driver up to date with the kernel or it will not work. You also have to remember you are running testing and things can and do go wrong compared to stable.

Comment: @kemotep I'm using kernel 5.2.0-3 and nvidia driver is 430.50

Comment: So to confirm you installed and maintain your nvidia driver via the debian repositories? Same for the kernel? Either way, new kernel means you will need a new kernel module. You will likely need to reinstall the driver. Nvidia and Linux is a big pain in my experience unless you are using a distro that specifically accounts for these problems. My advice is to either avoid nvidia, stick with stable (or at least stay on the same kernel version as the one you installed the nvidia driver on), or switch to a distro that offers better support for nvidia.